# Creating new Exception classes, new arguments

Tags: php, exception

I am writing some new code in which I want to use some self defined exceptions. For instance `TableCreationFailedException`. Since I'm using PHP the base class this is deriving from is the [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) class.

In case of this particular exception it needs to hold the table which could not be created.

I'm wondering how to best have this table field in the exception be set. A required argument in the constructor seems the way to go. Do I put the new argument at the front of the argument list? Shall I drop the message and arguments if I do not expect them to be needed? What are the conventions here, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules; something like this would work just fine:

```
class TableCreationFailedException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct($table, \Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct("Table $table could not be created", 0, $previous);
    }
}
```

In your case I would put the specialized argument `$table` in front of the ones the parent Exception constructor would accept.

It's also advisable to make sure you can chain exceptions together by adding `$previous` to the constructor arguments.

I've left out `$code`, which is now hardcoded as `0`; you could add it like this:

```
    public function __construct($table, $code = 0, \Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct("Table $table could not be created", $code, $previous);
    }
```